# How do i send text data from one computer to another wirelessly using java?

Tags: java

i have a good experience of socket programming in java using lan cable but I'm unable to find anything regarding the wireless transfer using java

plz help me out

Comment: Well, set up an 802.11 network, put both computers on it, use LAN-cable approach. Done.

Comment: Where were you when turning awards were being thrown?

Comment: If you connect the computers via WiFi there is nothing special you need to do.

Comment: Erm ... what is a "turning award"?  Why do you "throw" them?  Does it hurt if one hits you?

Answer (score 0):

Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/).

TCP or UDP can be used. TCP establishes a secure connection between the computers and ensures the delivery of the packages. UDP sends the package and it could be received or not. TCP is the most commonly used of the two, but UDP is mainly used for multiplayer video games.

Sending data over lan wirelessly should still work using sockets.